# Underextrusion on top of curves

Tags: ultimaker-cura, underextrusion, ultimaker-2

Every time I print a dome-like shape, some of the last layers will be under extruded. Strangely, the very last few layers extrude fine. So, I just end up with ugly unextruded halos on all of my prints with curves. My extrusion otherwise is fair otherwise.

[image]

Slicer: Cura

Printer: Ultimaker 2 Go w/ e3D v6 1.75 mm hotend

Filament: Prusament 1.75 mm PLA

Temp: 215 ˚C

Speed: 110 mm/s (trying to get fast - ultimate goal)

Retraction speed: 25 mm/s

Retraction distance: 2.5 mm